# iMacros for LinkedIn - How to Disable Instant Message Box in Chrome?

Tags: linkedin-api, imacros, event-listener

I'm running an iMacros script in LinkedIn.  Each time someone replies, the instant message box pops up and disrupts the macro.  How can I disable instant messaging in LinkedIn?

I can't find a solution in LinkedIn's site settings, so I figure it must be done through Chrome Console Event Listeners.  I'm just not sure which changes to make or how to do it.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the 'Messaging' bar by means of the following code:

```
URL GOTO=javascript:{document.querySelector("#msg-overlay").parentNode.removeChild(document.querySelector("#msg-overlay"));undefined;}
```

If this doesn't help, make your question more precise with adding more information regarding the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Do I add this to the iMacros script, or do I run it in Chrome console once?  When I ran it in Console, I receive an error related to 'undefined'. Thanks again.

Comment: I figured out that it goes in the iMacros script :-)  It appears to be working. I tried a test reply to see if it breaks the script. It appears to work.  Thanks for your help.  This was huge!